# Ошибка запуска Media Creation Tool 0x80072f8f - 0x20000

Tags: windows

Имеется компьютер с Windows 7, хочу обновить его до Windows 10 с сохранением данных.
Но не получается запустить Media Creation Tool, выдает ошибку с кодом 0x80072f8f - 0x20000. Пробовал все методы из интернета, но так и не получилось добиться результата. Подскажите, как можно избавиться от этой ошибки? Вот скрин ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ведь сделать без этой утилиты. Создайте установочную флешку и через биос сделайте запуск с неё. После запуска компьютера не чистите диски и ставьте 10 винду поверх 7. Старые файлы сохранятся на диске С в папке Old.Windows. После всех обновлений просто удалите старую винду Нужно подробнее объяснить или сможете самостоятельно разобраться?

Comment: Можно просто запустить setup.exe с диска win10.